# Moving files based on their name and extension to a folder matching the name of the file?

Tags: powershell, file, foreach, move

I'm in the process of preparing files for uploading into a content management system and they must be in sequentially numbered folders. Each folder will contain image and data files as .tif and .txt, respectively. Currently all the files are in one directory and the goal is to move each file into its corresponding folder.

I can move the files based on the extension and create a folder that matches using this script:

`$files = Get-ChildItem *.tif ; ForEach ($file in $files){$folder = New-Item -type directory -name $file.BaseName; Move-Item $file.FullName $folder.FullName;}`

This results in folders containing a single .tif with both the folder and the file having a matching name. This is step one.

I'm stuck on step two. **I have to move the .txt files that are currently in the parent directory into the matching folders based on the names.** **The goal is to have folders containing their matching .tif and .txt files.** For example, folder "0001" has "0001.tif" and "0001.txt" inside.

[Image of the parent directory with .txt and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fD0N.png)

Comment: why don't you get the files - all of them - and group by the `.BaseName`. then use the groups go create the target dirs & move them to the new dir?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've figured out how to create the groups, but now I'm stuck on the proper syntax to create a folder and move the groups. $files = Get-ChildItem *.tif, *.xml
$files | Group-Object -Property BaseName

Comment: Figured it out.

Comment: kool! you are quite welcome. glad to know that you got it working as needed ... [*grin*]